# What is the symbol of a static method call in a UML sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, modeling, sequence-diagram

I wasn't able to find this info in the official specs. Do they not prescribe a difference between a static method call and any other kind of message? In other words, simply put an arrow when the call occurs just like any other message? In that case there is no instantiated class participant available to point to, unless it is legal to just put the static classname without the ":" in front of it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108660/how-to-present-static-class-or-function-call-in-sequence-diagram might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent static call by targeting class rather than object in the sequence diagram (both classes and objects can coexist in sequence diagram).

Answer (score 1):

your question was already discussed on stackoverflow:
[How to present static class or function call in Sequence Diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108660/how-to-present-static-class-or-function-call-in-sequence-diagram)

So you might want to use a stereotype as indicated there. Hope it helps!